# Ways to accelerate reduce operation on Xeon CPU, GPU and Xeon Phi

Tags: hpc, intel-mkl, intel-mic, xeon-phi

I have an application where reduce operations (like sum, max) on a large matrix are bottleneck. I need to make this as fast as possible. Are there vector instructions in mkl to do that?

Is there a special hardware unit to deal with it on xeon cpu, gpu or mic?

How are reduce operations implemented in these hardware in general?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your own simple reductions using the KNC vpermd and vpermf32x4 instructions as well as the swizzle modifiers to do cross lane operations inside the vector units.

The C intrinsic function equivalents of these would be the *mm512*{mask}permute* and *mm512*{mask}swizzle* family.

However, I recommend that you first look at the array notation reduce operations, that already have high performance implementations on the MIC.

Look at the reduction operations available [here](https://www.cilkplus.org/tutorial-array-notation) and also check out [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=exW-P-T2GFY#t=1229) video by Taylor Kidd from Intel talking about array notation reductions on the Xeon Phi starting at 20mins 30s.

EDIT: I noticed you are also looking for CPU based solutions.  The array notation reductions will work very well on the Xeon also.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for an answer on similar lines.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out none of the hardware have reduce operation circuit built-in.
I imagined a sixteen 17 bit adders attached to 128 bit vector register for reduce-sum operation. Maybe this is because no one has encountered a significant bottleneck with reduce operation. Well, the best solution i found is `#pragma omp parallel for reduction` in openmp. I am yet to test its performance though.

Answer (score 0):

This operation is going to be bandwidth-limited and thus vectorization almost certainly doesn't matter.  You want the hardware with the most memory bandwidth.  An Intel Xeon Phi processor has more *aggregate* bandwidth (but not bandwidth-per-core) than a Xeon processor.